# Simple function approximation and square integral convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Let $f$ be continuous on some interval $0\leq S<T$ and choose a partition $\Pi_n=\{S=t_0<t_1<...<t_n=T\}$ and define $f_n=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}f(t_j)\cdot\chi_{[t_j,t_{j+1})}$. Why ***exactly*** does $f_n\rightarrow f$ and
$$\int_S^T(f-f_n)^2\>dt \rightarrow 0\>\> as \>\> n\rightarrow\infty.$$

Comment: As stated, there is no reason it would, since you have placed no demands on the partitions (note that you have to choose and different partition for each $n$, so that should be $\Pi_n$). In order tor this to be true, you at least must require that $|\Pi_n| = \sup_j (t_i - t_{i-1}) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ (I assume that $n \to 0$ in your post was a typo, as that would be ridiculous.)

Comment: @PaulSinclair Apologies, those were silly mistakes and I did mean for the mesh of the partition to go to zero as $n$ goes to infinity. So given that the mesh goes to zero does the square integral always go to zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\epsilon > 0$.

The closed interval $[S,T]$ is compact, so $f$ is uniformly continuous on it. Therefore there is a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x_1, x_2\in [S,T]$ with $|x_1 - x_2| <\delta, |f(x_1) - f(x_2)| <\epsilon$.

Since you say that indeed $|\Pi_n| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, there is an $N$ such that if $n > N$, then $|\Pi_n| < \delta$. For such an $n > N$, let $\Pi_n = \{t_j\}_{j=0}^n$. If $x \in [t_j, t_{j+1}]$, then $|x - t_j| < \delta$, so $$|f(x) - f_n(x)| = |f(x) - f(t_j)| < \epsilon$$
Therefore $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ for every $x \in [S, T]$.

And $$\left|\int_S^T (f(x) - f_n(x))^2\,dx\right| \le \int_S^T\left| (f(x) - f_n(x))^2\right|\,dx\le \int_S^T\epsilon^2\, dx = (T-S)\epsilon^2$$

And hence  $\int_S^T (f(x) - f_n(x))^2\,dx \to 0$

Comment: Thank you, you've helped with more questions than you know by helping me get that!

Comment: Out of interest, however, how do we know that $\int_S^T(f(x)-f_n(x))^2\>dx$ even exists? $f$ is continuous but $f_n$ isn't necessarily, so why is the integrand even integrable? In the same vein, if $h$ is bounded and $\{g_n\}$ is a sequence of bounded, continuous functions that converges to $h$, how do we know that $(h-g_n)^2$ is integrable?

Comment: $f_n$ is continuous except for a finite number of jump discontinuities. That is still integrable. As for the other, that is not directly related to this question, so I suggest you ask it separately in another thread.